# Return Mongoose query result through multiple methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I'm trying to retrieve data from a MongoDB database using Mongoose to access the data, however I am trying to retrieve the data through a few methods. Here is my `retrieveDocument` method:

```
function retrieveDocument(collectionName, schema, _id) {
    conn.once('open', async () => {
        var model = mongoose.model(collectionName, schema, collectionName)
        return await model.findById(_id)
    });
}
```

and how I'm calling the method:

```
function retrieveUserDocument(_id){
    return retrieveDocument("User", some_Schema, _id);
}
console.log(retrieveUserDocument("some_Id"));
```

However the result isn't being printed out, and instead the code is logging `undefined`, as the `model.findById(_id)` method returns a Promise.

How can I print out the result in the structure I have defined above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try promise here. It might work and you should try await when you are calling mongoose model. Try the code which is written below

```
function retrieveDocument(collectionName, schema, _id) {
    return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
        conn.once('open', async () => {
            var model = await mongoose.model(collectionName, schema, collectionName)
            resolve(model.findById(_id))
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I wrapped the connection in a promise and it worked! Just one or two changes: the `async` before `(resolve,reject)` wasn't necessary, and `await` before the `model` call didn't have any effect. Rather, I needed to keep it before the `model.findById()` call instead. Regardless, wrapping the connection call in a `Promise` and  calling `resolve` on the `find` call was what worked!